# Is $\mathbb R \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb R$ Noetherian ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, noetherian

Is $\mathbb R \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb R$ Noetherian ring ?

I understand that $\mathbb R \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb R$ being an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q$ is not Noetherian $\mathbb Q$ module but how can I show that it is Noetherian ring 
or not. Help me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any idea of the structure of the ring? What the ideals look like, for instance?

Comment: I don't know how the ideals look like in tensor product of two rings

Comment: It's an old result of Vamos that $K\otimes_kK$ is Noetherian iff $K$ is a finitely generated extension of $k$. Now you can conclude.

Comment: @user26857: Thank you for your information.